# Profiling Qt programs in macOS (Mac OS X) using Instruments

Tags: c++, macos, qt, instruments, macos-sierra

I am using TimeProfiler form Instruments to profile my Qt applications. Profiling works good, but the problem is that in the call tree contains a lot of Qt functions that sometimes isn't very useful. For example a have a function `view::world::CameraController::updateScreenCoordinate()` that calls every time user change pointer position on the screen. I have to unfold a lot of Qt framework functions before I rich my function:

[image]

It is very uncomfortable to search my functions every time I profile application. Is there any way to hide Qt functions in TimeProfiler?

Qt version 5.8 clang_64, macOS 10.12.3 Sierra, Instruments 8.2.1.

Comment: You probably need to enable "Hide System Symbols" in Call Tree settings. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-TimeProfiler.html "Call Tree settings" "Hide System Symbols" Off by default. Enable this option to hide system calls, allowing you to focus solely on your app’s symbols.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but it seems Instruments doesn't think that Qt library is System Library.  So it doesn't hide them.